# Javascript to get images from Json file and button next and previous functionality

Tags: javascript, html, css, json

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sQcZb.jpg%60) I am trying to get images from json file. when i click on the next button next image must come and when i press previous button previous image must come.I am getting image path but it is not showing image inside div. Please help me.

```js
function main() {

    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            myObj = JSON.parse(this.responseText);

           var x =document.getElementById("guitarimg");

           var y =myObj.allProducts[0].image_path;

         x.innerHTML = "<img src='y'>"

        }
    };
    xmlhttp.open("GET", "guitardata1.json.txt", true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
main();
```

```css
#div1
{
    border: 1px solid black;
    height: 700px;
    width:800px;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    left: 250px;
    top: 50px;
}

#demo
{
    position: relative;
    top: 30px;

}

div.navbar
{
    border:1px solid black;
    height:40px;
    width:600px;
    position: relative;
    left: 80px;
    top: 15px;
}

#guitarimg
{
    border: 1px solid;
    position: relative;
    height:300px;
    width: 500px;
    top: 30px;
    left: 120px;

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="guitar.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="guitar.css">

</head>
<body>
<div id="div1">


    <div class="navbar"></div>
          <div id="demo">
          </div>
    <div id="guitarimg"></div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: basic string concatenation.... `y` in your image tag is a string, not a variable.

Answer (score 0):

basic string concatenation. `y` in your image tag is a string, not a variable.

```
     var y =myObj.allProducts[0].image_path;
     x.innerHTML = "<img src='y'>"
                              ^ Not a variable
```

What you need to do is

```
     var y =myObj.allProducts[0].image_path;
     x.innerHTML = "<img src='" + y + "'>"
```

Another problem is you call the script in the head. It is possible for it to run BEFORE the element is rendered to the page. You should either set the script after the element OR call the method on document ready or window onload to ensure the div element is rendered.

I would move it to before the closing body tag.

```
  <script type="text/javascript" src="guitar.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: Hi                                                                                                                          I want to get images from json file and when i click on the next button it will show me next image and when i click on the previous button it will show me previous image.                                                                                                    If you want json data let me know

Answer (score 0):

```js
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            myObj = JSON.parse(this.responseText);

           var x =document.getElementById("guitarimg");

          // var y =myObj.allProducts[0].image_path;

           // x.innerHTML = "<img id='img' src='" + y + "'>"

        }
    };
    xmlhttp.open("GET", "guitardata1.json.txt", true);
    xmlhttp.send();
    var total =7;
    var a = 0;







function next() {
    // var y = myObj.allProducts.image_path;
    var temp = document.getElementById("img");

    //temp.innerHTML = "<img id='img' src='" + y + "'>"

    if (a <= total - 1) {

        //alert(x);
        temp.src = myObj.allProducts[a].image_path;
        a++;

    }
}


    function previous()
    {
        var temp= document.getElementById("img");


        if(a >= 1)
        {


            temp.src = myObj.allProducts[a-1].image_path;
            a--;


        }


}
```

```css
#div1
{
    border: 1px solid black;
    height: 700px;
    width:800px;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    left: 250px;
    top: 50px;
}


div.navbar
{
    border:1px solid black;
    height:40px;
    width:600px;
    position: relative;
    left: 80px;
    top: 15px;
}

#guitarimg
{

    position: relative;
    height:300px;
    width: 500px;
    top: 30px;
    left: 120px;

}
#img
{
    position: relative;
    height: 300px;
    width: 500px;
    top: 30px;
    left: 120px;
}

.button1
{
    position: relative;
    left: 100px;
}
.button2
{
    position: relative;
    left: 500px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="guitar.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="guitar.js"></script>


</head>
<body>
<div id="div1">


    <div class="navbar"></div><br><br><br>
    <img id="img" src="guitarImages/main.jpg"> <br><br><br>

    <button type="button" onclick="previous()" class="button1">Previous</button>&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <button type="button" onclick="next()" class="button2">Next</button>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Got it thanks epascarello